# Braintree External Extension order email label incorrect

Tags: order-email, magento2.3.5-p2, gene-braintree

We are using UK based Magento 2.3.x application. This gene commerce Braintree extension implemented after Show incorrect format Braintree order email with the payment method label

**Current Result**

- **cc_type** Visa
- **cc_number** xxxx-1850

**Expected Result**

- **Credit Card Type** Visa
- **Credit Card Number** xxxx-3209

If you anyone get the same problem, Please help me, thanks in advance